# Are PMLs also used for soft-matter structural dynamics modelling as they are commonly used in Wave Propagation modelling?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics, biology, soft-matter

Numerical modelling of waves by FDTD method makes use of PMLs to establish absorbing boundaries. I recently began modelling soft-material structural dynamics (for biological cells) using FEM where the outer boundaries are free to deform. Is there any necessity for PML like conditions in this case? Can propagating stresses in the material reflect on the boundaries?

Comment: Since you didn't get an answer, I thought I'd let you know that we have a tag just for TDTD here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/. You're welcome to ask the question again over there if you're still looking for an answer.